# Ambiguous call to a function

Tags: c++, overloading

I have four functions:

```
template<class Exception,class Argument>
 void allocate_help(const Argument& arg,Int2Type<true>)const;

 template<class Exception,class Argument>
 std::nullptr_t allocate_help(const Argument& arg,Int2Type<false>)const;

 template<class Exception>
 void allocate_help(const Exception& ex,Int2Type<true>)const;

 template<class Exception>
 std::nullptr_t allocate_help(const Exception& ex,Int2Type<false>)const;
```

but when I call:

```
allocate_help<std::bad_alloc>(e,Int2Type<true>()); //here e is of a std::bad_alloc type
```

I'm getting an error:
Error 3 error C2668: ambiguous call to overloaded function 
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your call matches both:

```
template<class Exception,class Argument>
 void allocate_help(const Argument& arg,Int2Type<true>)const;
```

with `Exception = std::bad_alloc` and `Argument = std::bad_alloc` (`Argument` is automatically deduced), and:

```
template<class Exception>
 void allocate_help(const Exception& ex,Int2Type<true>)const;
```

with `Exception = std::bad_alloc`. Hence the ambiguity of the call.

Also I think that your compiler should output all the matching function after the error line, so you could answer your question yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Because they are ambigious.

```
template<class Exception,class Argument>
std::nullptr_t allocate_help(const Argument& arg,Int2Type<true>)const;

template<class Exception>
std::nullptr_t allocate_help(const Exception& ex,Int2Type<true>)const;
```

The signature of the second function is a subset of the first one, which means that in the context of your function call they are the same of taking "any type" as first argument and Int2Type as second argument.

```
allocate_help<std::bad_alloc>(e,Int2Type<true>());
```

Can become either:

```
std::nullptr_t allocate_help<std::bad_alloc, std::bad_alloc>(const std::bad_alloc& arg,Int2Type<true>)const;
```

or

```
 std::nullptr_t allocate_help<std::bad_alloc>(const std::bad_alloc& ex,Int2Type<true>)const;
```

How would the compiler choose?

Comment: +1, but they don't have the exact same signature, the second version is a subset of the first, where types `Exception` and `Argument` are the same. Any call for which the template argument `Exception` and the type of the first argument to the function call will not be ambiguous.

Comment: How `Int2Type<true>` matches `Int2Type<false>`?

Comment: It doesnt.  They are totally different types, unrelated.  @ronag's answer is incorrect as posted.

Comment: @John: That's exactly what I've hinted!